Why is the Transgression of Temurah mentioned twice?
We find the transgression of Temura - תמורה mentioned twice in פרשת בחוקותי
In פרק כ”ז פסוק י

לֹ֣א יַחֲלִיפֶ֗נּוּ וְלֹֽא־יָמִ֥יר אֹת֛וֹ ט֥וֹב בְּרָ֖ע אוֹ־רַ֣ע בְּט֑וֹב וְאִם־הָמֵ֨ר יָמִ֤יר בְּהֵמָה֙ בִּבְהֵמָ֔ה וְהָֽיָה־ה֥וּא וּתְמוּרָת֖וֹ יִֽהְיֶה־קֹּֽדֶשׁ׃
One may not exchange or substitute another for it, either good for bad, or bad for good; if one does substitute one animal for another, the thing vowed and its substitute shall both be holy.

And in פרק כ”ז פסוק ל”ג

לֹ֧א יְבַקֵּ֛ר בֵּֽין־ט֥וֹב לָרַ֖ע וְלֹ֣א יְמִירֶ֑נּוּ וְאִם־הָמֵ֣ר יְמִירֶ֔נּוּ וְהָֽיָה־ה֧וּא וּתְמוּרָת֛וֹ יִֽהְיֶה־קֹּ֖דֶשׁ לֹ֥א יִגָּאֵֽל׃
One must not look out for good as against bad, or make substitution for it. If one does make substitution for it, then it and its substitute shall both be holy: it cannot be redeemed.

Why is it necessary for the Torah to mention it twice?

The summary of Temurah 13a-b at https://steinsaltz.org/daf/temura13/ reads in part as follows:

There are two separate passages that teach the law of temura – that it is forbidden to try and exchange a sanctified animal with another, bringing the replacement as a sacrifice in its stead. The first passage relates to any animal that has been sanctified as a korban (see Vayikra 27:9-10), while the second deals specifically with ma’aser behema – a tithed animal (see Vayikra 27:32-33).
In the Mishna on today’s daf, Rabbi Shimon explains that the law of temura is repeated in the second passage so that the ma’aser behema can serve as an archetype for the laws of temura. Thus we learn that the only animals that can become temura are those:
•  that are a private offering,
•  are dedicated to be sacrificed on the altar,
•  that come as an obligation and
•  do not come through a partnership.

The 10 Volume ArtScroll Sefer HaChinuch, footnote 3 to Mitzvah 351 (page 219 of volume 6) contains this explanation of the repetition:
“In addition to this verse [Vayikra 27:10] which refers to all offerings, the Torah (Leviticus 27:33) repeats the prohibition of temurah in the context of maasar beheimah [the animal tithe; Mitzvah 360]. See *Temurah” 13a-b for discussion of what this repetition teaches.”
